# Display additional product information (e.g. image caption) when hovering product image

Tags: css, wordpress, hover, woocommerce

I'm using using the WooCommerce plugin for WordPress to display my products. The thing is, when you are viewing the product category (archive), you can see the product name, image and price, but that doesn't really say all that much about exactly what the product is.

What I would like is for some more information to become available when you hover the product images. Something a bit like [this](http://shop.herriottgrace.com).
Would it be possible to retrieve some of the information about the image, that I can enter in the WordPress media libray: title, caption alt text or description?

You can check the webshop [here](http://renservice.dk/produkt-kategori/universalrengoering).

**EDIT:**

I found that editing the content-product.php file in the WooCommerce plugin folder, if I put this:

```
?>
random text
<?php
```

somewhere inside the php tags in the `<li>` section of that file, I could get 'random text' to show either above or below the product image on the product archive page. So, if I could replace that with a function that would retreive for instance the product image caption or some custom field that I can fill out for each product, that would go a long way towards solving the issue.
So, if anyone knows of a function that does this, please share it here.

Comment: just create costume fields for this

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate that?

Comment: Yeh sure !! just use Type plugin or any other  costume field plugin and add some costume fields for the additional information about your product. Like if you want to add model of your product then add a text line for model and call on the your single product page or where you need to show this fields .......

Comment: Adding a custom field is something that I reckon I'll be able to do, but I probably need some help getting it displayed on frontend on the products catalogue.

Answer (score 0):

```
hello sir just use this plugin
 https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-custom-product-data-fields/

for retrieving any costume fields do like this
Retrieving multiselect value



global $wc_cpdf;
$multiselect = $wc_cpdf->get_value($post->ID, '_mymultiselect');

foreach ($multiselect as $value) {

  echo $value;

}


Retrieving image value



global $wc_cpdf;

$image_id = $wc_cpdf->get_value($post->ID, '_myimage');

$size = 'thumbnail';

$image_attachment = wp_get_attachment_image($image_id, $size);

echo $image_attachment;

}
```

Comment: I installed the plugin and filled out one of the fields for some of the products. I still need to know exactly what code to insert exactly where in exactly which file.

Comment: which field you add and where do want to show this fields

Comment: The textarea field. Ideally I want to show it on the products catalogue (rchive) page on top of the product image when hovered.

Comment: global $wc_cpdf;
$textarea= $wc_cpdf->get_value($post->ID, '_mytextarea');

foreach ($textarea as  $value) {

  echo $value;

}

Comment: where you want to show you data  if on your single product page then add this field in your single product page or archive then add this on your archive

Comment: So I'm guessing you mean the archive-products.php file? If so, I'm stil clueless as to where in that file the above code goes.

Comment: I added it to the question.

Comment: go in woocommerce folder and then template single product folder and then chose file thumbnail file and put your code bellow or above your thumbnail of your product

Comment: Did it, but the field value is not showing up anywhere.

Comment: Cross check your code and see your documentation of your plugin ......it must be show if every things is oky

Comment: Exactly where are you expecting the field value to show?

Comment: I updated the question. If I'm not mistaken, I believe I found the correct place for inserting something that might go on top of the product image. I just need a function that can display image captions or custom fields in that place.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did this with a website for a client. I changed the hover text for each product from "Add to Cart" to the product short description. Here is my code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text' );    // 2.1 +
    
    function woo_archive_custom_cart_button_text() {
    //get the product object
    global $product;
    $id = $product->get_id();
    $descript = $product->get_short_description();

    //take out html from description
    $descript1 = strip_tags($descript);

    //shorten description length to fit the product image box
    if (strlen($descript1) > 100){
       $descript1 = substr($descript1, 0, 99) . '...';
    }
    
    return __( $descript1, 'woocommerce' );
    
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. There is your code ... that's really great so it is possible to help you. But is there a question?